# Battery advice re cooking equipment

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, battery-operated, battery-chemistry

Please go gentle as I am a novice at electronics/battery issues.

I am hoping someone with a much bigger brain than me can answer this question...

Is it realistically possible to power a 1200W hotplate with a battery and if so what sort of spec battery would I need?

I am looking to power something like this...

[image]

([Product link](https://www.klarstein.co.uk/Home-appliances/Hot-plates/Captain-Cook-Hotplate-Hob-Ceramic-Infrared-1200W-Stainless-Steel-Black-Black.html?gclid=CjwKCAiA5qTfBRAoEiwAwQy-6R2s-zfHfGcz7QNs58CT9i-At6rMLQt8CdkkjgfLnnutnTF8RE2JBxoCdYoQAvD_BwE))

My research shows me that an average kitchen hob uses around 0.72 kWh per use.  I'd imagine something like a portable hotplate would use less but this is a good measuring stick.

I truly appreciate anyone giving this any thought.

Thanks.

Comment: If the answer involves the use of *several* car batteries, would you still be interested?

Comment: The high-tech, lithium-polymer battery in my plug-in hybrid car supposedly stores enough energy to run your hot-plate for about six and a half hours. It weighs four hundred and fifty pounds (a bit more than 200 kg)

Comment: Thanks for your replies.  Several car batteries wouldn't be ideal  but if that's the only way I can do it at least I can write it off.

Comment: Solomon re your car, all joking aside with some basic maths that can at least provide some helpful information (although I'm sure it's not as simple as that!).  I'll need to power the plate for about half an hour so about 15kg worth of battery could work.  I was thinking/hoping that ballpark figure.  Anyone with any ideas where I could find one?

Comment: Can you provide information about your use situation?  If you're running off batteries, chances are you would benefit from finding cooking equipment you can run directly off DC so you won't have to feed the losses of a voltage converter/inverter.  Depending on whether you have solar available to charge the batteries or whether it's a mobile setup, and depending on sound constraints, a small 1500W generator might save you a lot of money in the long run.  Is this a portable kitchen?  Is there a weight limit?  Wheels on it?

Comment: Argh, new to the forum and tried to add a paragraph! Anyway it is for mobile cooking purposes where unfortunately a generator is not an option.  Solar power is limited (we are in the UK).  I'm just trying to see if there is anything on the market which could work.  I assumed in this day and age with the advances in battery performance there would be but I know how horrifically draining any heating/cooking can be on battery life.  Wheels can be made available for transport and all though I am not the brightest I have a strong back so moving it around should not be a problem within reason.

Comment: @nickjchelm - this isn't a forum. To add additional info you need to 'edit' your original question. But using 'stored electricity' to create heat is rarely an efficient use of the 'stored electricity' or the space used to store it. You'd get much better energy density by storing a liquid fuel (or liquified compressed gas) and burning it.

Comment: @nickjchelm put @ before a person's name when you reply to them and they get a notification to come back and answer you.  I'm only here because I decided to see if anyone else had posted.  Ok, so a generator is not an option, and your next question is whether this justifies a Li-Ion battery array or not.  Lead acid batteries are heavier and take up more space due to having lower energy density and power to mass ratio, but they have much better simplicity of use(it is harder to mistreat them), cost less and are much less dangerous when they are mistreated.

Comment: So whether to use lithium ion will be determined by how much space you have available and how much total capacity you need.

Comment: @AndrewMorton this is not an application for car starter batteries.  A car battery will drop dead after about 12 deep discharge cycles.   Deep-cycle SLA with an inverter would be an option.  An Li-ion automotive starter battery (Lithium Iron Phosphate(LiFePO4) solution would cost well over $1000 but can be deep cycled.

Comment: @KH Li-ion is determined by how deep your pockets are.  An Li-ion (Li-phosphate) battery for a car starter battery costs over $1000.  Maybe a motorcycle Li-ion would be affordable.

Comment: @Misunderstood yeah I would only go for lithium ion if the size/weight/capacity constraints didn't allow for lead acid.

Comment: @Misunderstood Perhaps I should have written "batteries the size of car batteries." My intention was to give an idea of the scale of batteries needed for a continuous draw of about 100 A before further work was warranted or suggesting that Campingaz might have [a more usable solution](https://www.campingaz.com/UK/c-552-1-and-2-burner-stoves.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: Possible? Yes.  Practical? No.

Some quick back of the envelope math... First of all, your stated 0.72kWh average, on a stove with a 1200W (1.2kW) power draw, means you're only getting 36 minutes of runtime before you need to recharge (0.72kWh/1.2kW = 0.6h).  But sometimes you may want to cook something that takes a little longer, so let's be more generous and plan for 1 hour of cooking, or 1.2kW of storage.

Suppose you use lithium-ion batteries.  A common lithium ion cell has a nominal voltage of 3.6V, and usually somewhere around 3000mAh of storage, for approximately $5.  That works out to approximately 10-12W of energy storage per cell.  Here's one example: https://www.18650batterystore.com/Panasonic-18650-p/panasonic-ncr18650b.htm .

If we were to construct a battery using these cells, we would need over 100 of them, which would be fairly bulky, and already we have $500 in cost not including the connections and electronics to make it all work.

If instead we used a cheaper battery chemistry, such as lead acid, it would greatly increase the size and weight, and it would be a stretch to call such a device "portable".  Here is a single-battery solution that would provide the needed 1200W, but it costs $290 and weighs 65lbs (30kg): https://www.batteriesplus.com/battery/sla-sealed-lead-acid/12/wkdc12=100p

And $300-500 could buy quite a lot of kerosene or propane for a more conventional portable stove, which would provide much more than an hour of runtime.

Comment: @nickjchelm:  Nate's deep-cycle lead-acid battery may manage to cook one meal - but how do you propose to recharge it for the next meal?  A propane or kerosene stove would be much more practical for an extended camping trip.